# How to add a public or private property in the class using public method in ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add a public or private variable in the class definition on calling a public method of a class for example in the class definition given below.

```
export default class Container {
  public addFlag(flagName: string): void {
     // create a new private or public property in class and assign a value to it.
  }
}
```

If I make an instance of container class and call `addFlag()` on that instance, I want to add a public or private variable in the class definition and assign a value to it, how can i achieve this in Typescript ?.

Comment: Declare the property in your class definition and give it a default value and type and then you can "assign" a value to it in the `addFlag()` method.  TypeScript is purposely not as flexible as Javascript for just randomly adding new properties of any type to an object.  You don't "add" something to a class definition in the execution of a method.  You add something to the class definition in the class definition.

Comment: But the use case, is that It should create a new property and assign the value every time the method gets called, can you please explain to me how you can achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: In plain Javascript, you just do `this.someProp = someValue;` inside the `addFlag()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class become dynamic object with [index signature][1]

```
class Container {
    [key: string]: any;
    public addFlag(flagName: string): void {
        this.flagName = flagName;
   }
}

const container = new Container();
container.addFlag("abc");
console.log(container.flagName); // "abc"
```

But index signature can't use `Access modifiers`: public, private or protected.